# Is it a proper JSON file?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization, json-deserialization

I stumbled upon the .json file structured in the following way:

```
"property1":"graph_example"

"property2":false
"property3":true
"property4":null

{ "objectType": "some_type", "name": "name_1", "operation": "operation_1", "numericValue": 3}
{ "objectType": "some_type", "name": "name_2", "operation": "operation_2", "numericValue": 4}
{ "objectType": "some_type", "name": "name_3", "operation": "operation_3", "numericValue": 1, "dependencies": [{"name":"operation_1","amount":10},{"name":"operation_2","amount":10}] }
```

The file describes a precedence graph, where `name_3` is dependant on `name_1` and `name_2`. I was trying to de-serialize it in Java (using Jackson) , but I think it is not a proper JSON. The elements are not enclosed in any kind of list and there are no commas separating entries. Some elements are not mandatory - if element has no dependencies the list of dependencies is simply missing. http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ which I tried to use to generate POJOs finds no data in this structure. Or is it some special JSON-like format?

Comment: I'm also guessing that the `dependencies"` in the last line is supposed to have a `"` before it and that's just a copy-paste error.

Comment: A legal JSON file will always start with `{` or `[`.  And as you indicate, the elements are not comma-separated, which they should be in JSON.

Comment: Go to json.org for a very simple but precise description of the JSON syntax.  And Google "JSON online parser" or "JSON verifier" for online tools that will syntax-check JSON for you.

Comment: @MosheKatz you are right, that was my copy-paste error

Comment: @HotLicks yeah this is what I have found everywhere. So probably I have to pre-format the files before parsing or parse them manually

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>It looks like valid [CSON](https://github.com/bevry/cson) **except that it needs `{` and `}` added at the beginning and end**. I ran this:</strike>

```
CSON.parseFileSync("test.cson");
```

... and I got this back:

```
{ objectType: 'some_type',
  name: 'name_3',
  operation: 'operation_3',
  numericValue: 1,
  dependencies: 
   [ { name: 'operation_1', amount: 10 },
     { name: 'operation_2', amount: 10 } ] }
```

---

At first glance, it **looked** like valid [CSON](https://github.com/bevry/cson).  However, it obviously is not, based on the fact that only the last line of the file is actually successfully parsed.

When I try adding `{` and `}` around the file contents, to try to make the parser see it as a whole object, I get this result:

```
{ [SyntaxError: unexpected {]
  location: 
   { first_line: 7,
     first_column: 0,
     last_line: 7,
     last_column: 0 },
  toString: [Function],
  code: '{\n"property1":"graph_example"\n\n"property2":false\n"property3":true\n"property4":null\n\n{ "objectType": "some_type", "name": "name_1", "operation": "operation_1", "numericValue": 3}\n{ "objectType": "some_type", "name": "name_2", "operation": "operation_2", "numericValue": 4}\n{ "objectType": "some_type", "name": "name_3", "operation": "operation_3", "numericValue": 1, "dependencies": [{"name":"operation_1","amount":10},{"name":"operation_2","amount":10}] }\n}',
  filename: '/home/mmkatz/test.cson' }
```

This appears to be because the lat few items in the file should be an array, but there are no `[` and `]` around them.

---

In the end, I'm going to have to say that this is some kind of custom format which has only incidental similarity to JSON or CSON.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not.

The enclosing `{}` are missing, and some items are missing their respective keys.

The last three rows are three separate valid json documents and the first 5 rows would be valid if they had been enclosed in `{}` and comma-separated.